# Vertical scroll bar remove

Tags: html, css

Why div's are overflowing.I am getting vertical scroll bar.Some one please explain clearly where I did mistake.

If I remove any of the comment its working fine.

```
 * {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
           box-sizing: border-box;
    }
body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
       /*overflow: hidden;*/

}
#box {
        position: relative;
        width: 9%;
        height: 9%;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 1% 1%;
        position: relative;
       /*float: left;*/

}
```

html code

```
<html>
        <body>
                <div id="box"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `height:100%` is what's causing this, you can either set to 99% or use `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: I just want to know why two divs are overflowing. Any way to solve with out using overflow hidden;

Comment: You can also use `position: absolute;` with `height: 100%`. I'm not exactly sure why this is happening but you already have 3 solutions. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is happening due to [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

A trick is to add some empty content in the `:before`/`:after` of the container (*`body` in this case*)

```
body:before,
body:after{
        content:'';
        display:block;
        height:0;
        width:0;
        overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

Full working Demo:

```css
* {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
           box-sizing: border-box;
    }
body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
}
body:before,
body:after{
        content:'';
        display:block;
        height:0;
        width:0;
        overflow:hidden;
}
#box {
        position: relative;
        width: 9%;
        height: 9%;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 1% 1%;
        position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: An easier way is to add float:left;

Comment: what about IE7 :before and :after properties will not work in IE7

Comment: Global IE7 usage is 0.09%

Comment: In the cases where :before and :after are not supported you can still use float:left, absolute positioning or other tricks from the supplied links.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: after reading your question again and checking out the provided code the problem you are actually facing is that the div forces the body to get bigger than 100%.

This is because a non-floated block element (div, h1, etc.) that is the first element of its parent forces its margin outside the parent's boundaries. It's a common thing seen with H1 tags inside divs that force their top-margin to be outside the wrapping div. This is called collapsing margins and a detailed explanation and workarounds can be found here: [Collapsing Margins](http://www.seifi.org/css/understanding-taming-collapsing-margins-in-css.html)

Basically a `floated`, `display:block` would take care of the issue, or use `position:relative;` along with `top:1em;left:1em;`

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

When you have a div with a set height and/or width (as is the case in your example) and you put text, images or other elements in there that are bigger than the div, an overflow will occur. So the solution is to either:

1. Put less content in the div
2. Don't make it a set height/width
3. use `overflow:hidden;`, `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:scroll;` to force the scrollbar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's beacuse you give  `margin: 1% 1%;`. Just remove it. Then it will solve your issue.

```
* {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
           box-sizing: border-box;
    }
body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
}
#box {
        position: relative;
        width: 9%;
        height: 9%;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 1% 1%;
        position: relative;

}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkuLjvsL/1/)

Answer (score -1):

If the element's contents are larger than the element's size, it will show a scroll-bar.

To change this use:

```
#box {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```